# Compiling and linking C code without any additional data in output file

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, ld, osdev

I am asking for help by professionals because of lack of my knowledge in using GCC and ld.I'm writing OS for educational purposes, and i have a problem with compiling and linking C code. To be honest, the is no any problem, but I'm confused by the unncessary data in output files generated by the GCC and LD like

```
GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 symtab..strtab..shstrtab..text..eh_frame..data..comment
.ELF..|
```

and etc.
I really need to know which parameters use both with gcc and ld to reduce this unuseful (for my OS) data

Parameters I used before: -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
-fstrength-reduce -finline-functions
I also use linker script to organise segments.

I tried objcopy to reduce such blocks as .comment and .note from output, for me it was the best solution

```
objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel.o kernel.bin
```

Comment: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem can be solved with the linker script. Using `/DISCARD/` block. Ld manual says that this block excludes everything listed in it from final output.

So I've inserted this block after the `.text`, `.data` and `.bss` blocks

```
/DISCARD/ : 
{
    *(.comment)
    *(.eh_frame)
    *(.note.GNU-stack)
}
```

As well as this line in the very beginning of my linker script to make output a plane binary file.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
```

Therefore, I do not need to use `objcopy` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Split you compilation and linking stages. Use the "-s" option for GCC to reduce .o files. (the link in pmg's comment is of particular interest, though not related to linker scripts)

The linker's script for a simple kernel is described [here (tutorial for building the kernel using LD)](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/basickernel.htm).

Use the

```
ld -T <yourscript> <objectfilelist> -o kernel.bin
```

command to get the desired binary.